# How to create a graph and its schema without using Datastax Studio but through Java?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

I was trying to create my first connection with DSE Graph through java..

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        DseCluster dseCluster = null;

        try {
            dseCluster = DseCluster.builder()
                    .addContactPoint("192.168.1.43")
                    .build();
            DseSession dseSession = dseCluster.connect();
            GraphTraversalSource g = DseGraph.traversal(dseSession, new GraphOptions().setGraphName("graph"));
            GraphStatement graphStatement =  DseGraph.statementFromTraversal(g.addV("test"));
            GraphResultSet grs = dseSession.executeGraph(graphStatement.setGraphName("graph"));
            System.out.println(grs.one().asVertex());
        } finally {
            if (dseCluster != null) dseCluster.close();
        }
    }
```

At first I was getting that "graph" doesn't exist.. I had to create a connection to the specific graph through DataStax Studio since it wasn't there..

Now I need to put the labels,properties etc in the schema.. I know how to do it in the studio (https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/using/createSchemaStudio.html) but I would like to do it in the code instead. How can I have access to the schema object in Java so I can make changes like those:

```
schema.config().option('graph.schema_mode').set('Development')
schema.vertexLabel('test').create()
```

also how is it possible to create a graph that doesn't exist through code? I tried to search through the java-dse-graph driver code but I didn't find anything :/

Thanks!

Comment: it seems it is not yet implemented: https://github.com/datastax/java-dse-graph/tree/1.x/manual#programmatic-schema-api

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @user2572801 still not implemented https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JAVA-1061

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can set graph options with a SimpleGraphStatement, as the docs show:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse/1.1/manual/graph/#graph-options

Comment: Thank you @polandll! So it is possible to change schema with it too?

Comment: @MichailMichailidis have you found any solution for this, please update the post if any solution.

Comment: A SimpleGraphStatement can be used to pass any graph statement to DSE Graph. So you could set/change schema with it. However, keep in mind that changing schema within an application is not a good idea. In addition, in DSE Graph, the only current concept of "changing schema" is adding a property; changing vertex labels or edge labels is not allowed.