# Is executeGraph() really needed in DSE 5.0 Graph with Java?

Tags: java, cassandra, gremlin, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

It seems that in both approaches the vertex is stored and can be retrieved properly later.

Common configuration:

```
DseCluster dseCluster = DseCluster.builder()
        .addContactPoint("192.168.1.43")
        .build();
DseSession dseSession = dseCluster.connect();
GraphTraversalSource g = DseGraph.traversal(
    dseSession, new GraphOptions().setGraphName("graph")
);
```

Approach 1:

```
Vertex v = g.addV("User").property("uuid","testuuid231").next();
```

Approach 2:

```
GraphStatement graphStatement =  DseGraph.statementFromTraversal(
    g.addV("User").property("uuid","testuuid231")
);
GraphResultSet grs = dseSession.executeGraph(graphStatement.setGraphName("graph"));
Vertex v = grs.one().asVertex() // as(Vertex.class) is not allowed after 1.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using [`java-dse-graph`](https://github.com/datastax/java-dse-graph), is that right?  This is a relatively new API (still in beta) which allows you to make Gremlin Traversals w/ Apache Tinkerpop using the DataStax Enterprise Java driver under the covers.

The benefits of approach 1 is that you can be sure that you are forming valid traversals for one, although you also get this via `statementFromTraversal` (you can also pass a `String` or `GraphStatement` into `executeGraph` at which point you can't be sure you are executing a valid traversal).  Additionally, you can write code that is more vendor agnostic, since you are using the Tinkerpop API and not the datastax driver. Well, you are still using it, but not directly once you've got a `GraphTraversalSource` from a `DseSession`.

Approach 2 has a few benefits that aren't available in approach 1 (yet):

1. If you are familiar with the datastax driver, you can use a lot of the same APIs that you are comfortable with (`ResultSet`, `Statement`, etc.).
2. The async API for TinkerPop ([TINKERPOP-1490](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1490)) was very recently added and I'm not sure it would work with `java-dse-graph` (haven't tried it yet).  Using `statementFromTraversal`, you can pass the generated `GraphStatement` into `DseSession.executeAsync` to do async.
3. DSE Graph has a schema API that is not part of Gremlin.  Therefore, you can't make schema changes with TinkerPop alone.  [JAVA-1061](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1061) will introduce a schema API for doing this using `java-dse-graph`.  Until then you would have to use `executeGraph(String|GraphStatement)`.
4. You can execute full groovy/gremlin code with approach 2.  This allows you to do things like transaction management and execute multiple traversals in one call, which you can't currently do with approach 1.

I expect that `java-dse-graph` (approach 1) will become the more idiomatic way to interact with DSE Graph in the future.  `statementFromTraversal` offers a nice way to get the best of both worlds (the benefit of Apache TinkerPop + an interface to the DataStax java driver).

Comment: thanks for the explanation :). I was trying to see what was causing things to be committed.. and it seems it is the .next() in approach 1.. this "converts" the GraphTraversal to a Vertex and it is already stored.. I was trying to migrate my TitanDB code to DataStax and I had a lot of places that I was passing Vertex around which now need to be GraphTraversals before they are executeGraph()'d

Comment: Is 3) related to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228539/how-to-create-a-graph-and-its-schema-without-using-datastax-studio-but-through-j

Comment: Most importantly the two differ because the one with executeGraph returns DSE Vertex objects and the other one returns Gremlin/Tinkerpop Vertex objects (this omission led me to http://stackoverflow.com/q/41261845/986160 - if you don't mind please add that in your answer for completeness. Thanks :)

Comment: It also seems that transaction handling is implicit so currently if executeGraph is not used with string gremlin queries, the fluent api traversals for gremlin become very difficult (if impossible) to write so they are all within a single transaction