# How to return a Vertex in the tinkerpop/gremlin format instead of the DSE graph format?

Tags: java, datastax, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am trying to return a Vertex (in tinkerpop format) that it was just created with Gremlin:

```
DseCluster dseCluster = DseCluster.builder()
        .addContactPoint(DbC.dseHost)
        .build();
DseSession dseSession = dseCluster.connect();
GraphTraversal traversal = graph.addV(VertexLabels.User)
        .property("username", "testuser")
GraphStatement graphStatement = DseGraph.statementFromTraversal(
    traversal
);
GraphResultSet grs = dseSession.executeGraph(graphStatement.setGraphName(DbC.graphName));
Vertex v = grs.one().as(Vertex.class);
```

and I am getting this exception...

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.datastax.driver.dse.graph.DefaultVertex cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex`

How could the code be changed so that it returns in gremlin.structure.Vertex format instead of the DSE Graph Vertex format?

I am using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>dse-driver</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1-beta1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-dse-graph</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope this can be done otherwise migration from TitanDB will be painful..

Comment: Try `.asVertex()` instead of `.as(Vertex.class)`

Comment: Thank you @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs.. asVertex() returns dse graph Vertex which completely different than gremlin structure Vertex (which is the standard) though.

Comment: I've asked what is their decision with Fluent API here: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1250

Comment: Do you meet the requirements mentioned in: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse/1.0/manual/graph/#using-tinkerpop-gremlin-core-api

Comment: Namely: `WARNING: please make sure that your version of Tinkerpop is compatible. The driver has been compiled and tested against version 3.2.0-incubating; it does NOT provide any compatibility guarantees for older Tinkerpop versions.`

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs let me check - it might be that titan is bringing in old version of Gremlin

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs I removed all Titan dependencies and I get the same error.. When I try to add version 3.2.0-incubating of gremlin in my pom I get ClassNotDefExceptions etc..

Comment: @PANAYIOTIS aparently 1.1 that I am using handles things differently :/
https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse/1.1/manual/graph/#deserializing-complex-data-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the lengthy discussion I had with Datastax Team through [jira](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1250?focusedCommentId=38313&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-38313) and emails:

It is indeed possible to have Fluent API and get back pure Gremlin/tinkerpop objects. This is possible as illustrated here ([java-dse graph 1.x documentation](https://github.com/datastax/java-dse-graph/tree/1.x/manual#tinkerpop-direct-compatibility)) using next(), toList() directly on GraphTraversalSource and not using executeGraph() which will return the DSE Objects.

So the above code changes to:

```
Vertex user = graph.addV("User")
                 .property("username", "testuser").next();
```

where `graph` is a `GraphTraversalSource<Vertex,Vertex>` object and `Vertex` is a `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex` object.

Answer (score 0):

In Datastax `1.1` it seems that you can't cast to `Vertex` directly, there is no indication of this in the documentation.

Instead you can access `VertexProperty` (`org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty`) using `.getProperties(String)`.

```
GraphNode n = dseSession.executeGraph("g.V().hasLabel('test_vertex_meta_props')").one();
Vertex vertex = n.asVertex();

// there can be more than one VertexProperty with the key "meta_property"
Iterator<VertexProperty> metaProps = vertex.getProperties("meta_property");

VertexProperty metaProp1 = metaProps.next();
// the value of the meta property
int metaProp1Value = metaProp1.getValue().asInt();
// the properties of the meta property itself
Iterator<Property> simpleProps1 = metaProp1.getProperties();
Property simpleProp11 = simpleProps1.next();
double simplePropValue11 = simpleProp11.getValue().asDouble(); 
Property simpleProp12 = simpleProps1.next();
double simplePropValue12 = simpleProp12.getValue().asDouble(); 

// **multi value** meta property.
VertexProperty metaProp2 = metaProps.next();
```

Via: [Datastax Manual (1.1)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver-dse/1.1/manual/graph/#a-word-on-properties)

Comment: That won't do .. unfortunately .. it is not by Gremlin standards that I've been coding around for about 1 year waiting for the migration to happen smoothly from TitanDB to DSE Graph! Yeah I saw the new API as I said in my comment - this is frustrating :(